# configuring maven beanstalker plugin beanstalk:wait-for-environment mojo

Tags: maven, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've successsfully deployed my app to elastic beanstalk using

`$ mvn beanstalk:upload-source-bundle beanstalk:create-application-version beanstalk:update-environment`

I'm able to watch in the AWS console that the environment is updated correctly. When I try to chain beanstalk:wait-for-environment, maven polls every 90 seconds and never detects that the environment is Ready.

One thing I noticed is that it's waiting for 'environment null to get into Ready', and it's looking for the environment to have a specific domain ********.elasticbeanstalk.com. I don't know how to change that, or disable that check

```
$ mvn beanstalk:upload-source-bundle beanstalk:create-application-version beanstalk:update-environment beanstalk:wait-for-environment  
...  
[INFO] Will wait until Thu Aug 22 10:59:37 PDT 2013 for environment null to get into Ready  
[INFO] ... as well as having domain ********.elasticbeanstalk.com  
[INFO] Sleeping for 90 seconds
```

My plugin config in pom.xml looks like this (company confidential names hidden)

```
<plugin>  
  <groupId>br.com.ingenieux</groupId>  
  <artifactId>beanstalk-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
  <version>1.0.1</version>  
  <configuration>  
    <applicationName>********-web-testing</applicationName>  
    <s3Key>********-2.0-${BUILDNUMBER}.war</s3Key>  
    <s3Bucket>********-web-deployments</s3Bucket>  
    <artifactFile>target/********-2.0-SNAPSHOT-${BUILDNUMBER}.war</artifactFile>  
    <environmentName>********-web-testing-fe</environmentName>  
  </configuration>  
</plugin>
```

Does anyone have insight into using beanstalk:wait-for-environment to wait until the environment has been updated?

Comment: Why do you need to use w-f-e?  (btw, there is a nice google group at beanstalker-users@groups.google.com)

Comment: wait-for-environment is only needed (in part) when you need a build pipeline involving zero downtime (with cname replication). You can basically ignore this mojo if you're not concerned about downtime (which is not really needed for testing environments)

Comment: The solution to the problem was that I need to add a cnamePrefix configuration parameter in my pom
<cnamePrefix>********-web-testing-fe-apfvmpzrp9</cnamePrefix>

Now beanstalker:wait-for-environment waits appropriately and finishes when the env is updated

Comment: you're right, I'm not concerned about downtime, but creating a new environment just takes a long time

Comment: unfortunately, thats the way it is (don't blame my mojo! :])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wait-for-environment is only needed (in part) when you need a build pipeline involving zero downtime (with cname replication). It all boils down to cnamePrefix currently. You can basically ignore this warning if you're not concerned about downtime (which is not really needed for testing environments)

Actually, the best way is to use fast-deploy. Use the archetype as an start:

`$ mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=elasticbeanstalk`